# Will code wait for return before continuing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I using the below code to set elements in an array and return the array, the returned array is then passed to another method for more changes before again being returned.

```
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//call checkTP1
returnArray = [self checkTP1STD:addingTime :startToTP1 :TP1Result :nowDate :sevenHour :totalrest :returnArray];


//call check TP2
returnArray = [self checkTP2STD:addingTime :startToTP2 :TP2Result :nowDate :sevenHour :totalrest :returnArray :tp2Rest];
```

It is currently working as expected, my question is will it always wait for the checkTP1STD to return before executing checkTP2STD?

I have split the code into multiple methods to enable it to be more readable as i will be adding some other logic to pass different variable values to the methods,just wanted to make sure my basic idea will work.

Comment: Yes, `checkTP2STD` won't execute until `checkTP1STD` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: yes

Your question is curious, you seem to be concerned that `checkTP1STD` will return before `checkTP2STD` is called, but not that the calls to `alloc` and `init` will return before the call to `checkTP1STD`.

Are you actually intending to do asynchronous work in `checkTP1STD` (E.g. Using GCD or system framework methods which state they are async). If so the answer is still yes, but the call may return before all the work scheduled by `checkTP1STD` is complete - the very nature of asynchronous programming.

HTH

Comment: There will be no async calls.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes. Code is executed in sequential order unless there's explicit calls to new threads, which you're not doing by the code you've given.